# FPDF How to force a page break

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using FPDF (1.7) to convert a TXT file into PDF.  I would like to force a page break in the PDF product.  The text file is created using php, and successfully uses carriage returns (\r).  But I cannot get form feeds (\f) to appear in the PDF.

Is there another way to force a page break in FPDF by either changing the original text file or the php code?  Perhaps a different character?  For now, I have a tilde marking where pages should break.

If it is of any interest, I will post the simple php used to call FPDF:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A5');
$pdf->AddPage('P'); 
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(real,'default');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$txt = file_get_contents('comments.txt', true);
$pdf->Write(8, $txt);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an idea:
Edit: complete code

```
<?php
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A5');
    $pdf->AddPage('P'); 
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode(real,'default');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $txt = file_get_contents('comments.txt', true);
    $pages = explode('~', $txt);
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $pdf->Write(8, $page);
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Brief explanation in case not clear: Splits the text up into 'pages' and writes each of them with a page break in between.

Possible bugs: adding extra page at the end.
Solution: iterate with for loop instead of foreach and stop one page short.

Another possible bug: won't be able to ever use tilde again.
(Bad) solution: use a more complex string to signify a page break.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I didn't know about explode.  I am a beginner.  Because the code is brief, could you please edit your idea to include the complete code?  I'm not sure how to fit it into my original code.

Comment: @user3283304 No worries, done! Basically replace the part where you $pdf->Write() the whole document with writing it 'page by page' with an AddPage() after each page.

Comment: Thank you!  It's an elegant solution and works. I will take your advice about page breaks too.